# For G a connective reductive algebraic group, can I find H semisimple and a closed embedding G into H such that Bun_G -> Bun_H is an immersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a connected reductive algebraic group over an algebraically closed field and let $X$ be a smooth projective curve. I want to find a semisimple algebraic group $H$ and a closed embedding $G\rightarrow H$ such that the induced map of moduli stacks of principal bundles $\operatorname{Bun}_G \rightarrow \operatorname{Bun}_H$ is injective on tangent spaces. Since the tangent space of $\operatorname{Bun}_G$ at $P$ is $H^1(X,\mathfrak{g}_P)$ and similarly for $H$, this amounts to finding $H$ and an embedding $G\rightarrow H$ such that the induced map $H^1(X,\mathfrak{g}_P)\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathfrak{h}_P)$ is injective for all bundles $P$. Is this possible?

Comment: In characteristic $0$, any $H$ works since the map on tangent spaces $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak h$ is injective and then it splits as a map of representations of $G$ since $G$ is reductive, so using this splitting the map on cohomology is injective. (Note, though, that the injectivity on tangent spaces does not imply the map is a closed immersion, by the usual definition, for stacks.)

Comment: To add to Will’s final comment,  the map of stacks is injective on isomorphism classes of objects only if $G$ is already semi simple..  Indeed,  the quotient morphism from $H$ to the coset space $H/G$ is a $G$-torsor whose associated $H$-torsor is trivial.  A trivialization of the original $G$-torsor gives a retraction of $H$ onto $G$, which quickly implies that $G$ is semisimple.

Comment: ... Now you can use results by Biswas and dos Santos to find a map of a curve to $H/G$ such that the pullback of the $G$-torsos is still nontrivial.

Comment: Ah yes of course!